# JavaFX Button Event Handler & Return Methods

Tags: java, recursion, javafx

I'm trying to create a button that will take a number from one textfield, run through a method with a return value and then set the text in a new textfield with that result. 
Here is the action I'm trying to do and the method I'm trying to call.

```
butCalcFact.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    String text = tfInput.getText();
                    tfResult.setText(Long.toString(tfInput.factorial()));
                }
            });

/** Return the factorial for the specified number */
public static long  factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) // Base case
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1); // Recursive call
}
```

Comment: `factorial()` takes an int but you're not passing anything to it here `tfInput.factorial()`

Comment: How can I pass a number that is inputted into the first textfield (tfInput)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing any integer into the factorial method.

```
butCalcFact.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    tfResult.setText(factorial(Integer.parseInt(tfInput.getText())) + "");
});
```